# Order Table by Column, but ignore if 0 - SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a column called `my_order`.  It is default to `0`.  I want to do this in my query:

`ORDER BY my_order (IF NOT 0)`

So if the columns' data has `0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1`, it would resort as `1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,` (ignoring the zeros).

Obviously that last part is incorrect.  How would I do this in `SQLite`?

My first two suspicions are either COALESCE or CASE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CASE like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
ORDER BY CASE WHEN my_order = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
my_order
```

Answer (score 0):

`order by case when my_order = 0 then 1 else 0 end, my_order`